# Using a UIImageView variable declared in another block

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to recall an image that I load in `(void)viewDidLoad` in another block, `(void)moveObject`. However, because I'm dealing with two different blocks, I apparently can't recall the image. Is there some way I should rearrange the code to be able to make it work?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(200.0f, 350.0f, 52.0f, 100.0f);
    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flake.png"]];
    myImage.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myImage];

    moveObjectTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) moveObject { 
    myImage.center = CGPointMake(myImage.center.x, myImage.center.y +1);
}
```

Comment: Note: Those aren't blocks, those are methods. Blocks has a whole different meaning.

Comment: In your situation, instead of the term "block" I'd use something along the lines of "method".  Edit: ninja'd by rmaddy ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance variable for myImage, or a property if you'd like getters and setters as well.

Here's how with just an instance variable:

.m

```
@implementation MyClass {

    UIImageView *_myImage;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(200.0f, 350.0f, 52.0f, 100.0f);
    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flake.png"]];
    myImage.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myImage];
    _myImage = myImage;
}

-(void) moveObject { 
    _myImage.center = CGPointMake(_myImage.center.x, _myImage.center.y +1);
```

Comment: With modern Objective-C, you should put the ivar in the @implementation block in the .m file instead of showing the world your private variables in the .h file.

Comment: Not quite what I meant. That is a valid option but instead of adding the class extension (or private category as you did), just put the curly braces on the @implemenation line and add the ivars in those curly braces.